# Raising melting point of water at STP (using disolved impurities)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, phase, temperature, entropy

Typically, water experiences melting point depression when it is impure. The more impure it is, the lower the melting point, up to a point.

I understand you could raise the melting point by increasing pressure, as discussed here: [How to RAISE the melting point of water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25123/how-to-raise-the-melting-point-of-water/25127#25127)

However, are there any impurities known that **increase** the melting point of the water. Ideally, whilst still being mostly water.

Comment: *I understand you could raise the melting point by increasing pressure* It is rather converting ice to more compact ice structures with higher melting points. But the needed pressure is not convenient. :-) // Impurities generally decrease melting point of major substance. Many salt hydrates have high melting points, rather dissolving themselves in own crystal water, but I guess it is not what you want.

Comment: When this kind of topic comes up, I like to cite [tetrabutylammonium hydroxide 30-hydrate](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sial/86859). Consisting of 67.5% water by weight, it can be isolated as a pure solid with a melting point around 27 °C. You could interpret this as an impurity which raises the melting point of ice by almost 30 °C. This is the hydrate with the highest water content I know that is a solid at room temperature, but others may exist with even more water.

Comment: When the pressure is about 1 bar, the melting point decreases when increasing the pressure, This tendency is reversed if the pressure is extremely high, and higher thant 1000 bar, which is not easy to obtain,

Comment: The more D and T atoms in water, the higher melting point.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150905/effect-of-impurities-on-melting-and-boiling-points

Comment: See "How to RAISE the melting point of water?" at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25123/how-to-raise-the-melting-point-of-water